# Finding the location of the JDK that runs the compiler in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Is there any convenient way (other than using the JAVA_HOME env variable which may not be set) to find the location of the JDK that gradle uses to run for example the javaCompile task within a gradle project?

Comment: Have you tried running this in terminal `gradle -version | grep JVM` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The question was about how to get the JDK location within the build script. I figured it out and posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually stumbled upon an answer to this by accident when I had resorted to cloning the gradle repository in an attempt to hunt down how the `compileJava` task figured out which compiler to use. I actually gave up on that but for the fun of it I decided to read through the `build.gradle` file in the gradle project itself.

Lo and behold, I found this line:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/989b3147970b70bb519014c0ed55dc3de33b479e/build.gradle#L115

So doing the following in my `build.gradle` gives me the location to the JDK that's being used to run Gradle:

`def jvm = org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
println jvm.javaHome.toString()`